# Property 'myFunction' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this error: `Property 'myFunction' of object [object Object] is not a function`

```
myFunction= (function(){
    //something
})();

myFunction();
```

What's wrong here? Can I call my self-executing function again? This is not working either if I use a var in my self-executing function.

Comment: Your function body doesn't return a function.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot clearer in how you think this relates to AJAX or "non-async". There's no indication *whatsoever* that your assumption is correct; the code you've posted has nothing to do with AJAX, and making a function self-executing doesn't somehow make it "non-async".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping your function call in brackets

```
(function (){ 
    // do something
})();
```

you are creating a function expression that gets executed immediately. The results of the function expression will then be assigned to your variable `myFunction`

You might want something like this:

```
var myFunction = (function (){
    return {
        doStuff : function(myVariable){
            // do stuff
        }    
    };
})();
```

This creates a return object that is assigned to the `myFunction` variable. One of the properties of this return object is `doStuff` which is a function that takes a variable which you can then call like

```
myFunction.doStuff('hello world');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the *return value* to `myFunction`. If your return value isn't a function, then `myFunction` isn't a function, and you can't invoke it.

If you want to store the function to execute it again later, you don't want a self-executing function expression:

```
myFunction= function(){
    //something
};

myFunction();
```

Comment: I want to run it as I want to make ajax non-async

Comment: That has nothing to do with making it self-executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction = function(){};

myFunction();
```

You have to create a function to call. The self calling closure is not returning a function.

Comment: I want to run it as I want to make ajax non-async

Comment: There is no need for the closure in that case. Look at the JQuery ajax api and the asynch=false setting

Comment: @user3318525: why do you want AJAX to be synchronous? You probably need to change the way you're going about using AJAX.

Comment: @user3318525: Immediately invoked function expressions have nothing to do with Ajax or asynchronicity. Sounds like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you describe the **actual** problem you are trying to solve, we could help you better.